# RxJS inside React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

The bulk of this problem is that I'm trying to create react components that each have an observable based on the component's props.  I have several locations, each with environmental readings, that I would like to independently generate D3 graphs for using RxJS to manage data coming in.

I have a working version of this concept here:

https://www.lloydrichardsdesign.com/experiment/021

The problem I'm having is with this example, I've hardcoded the firestore observable outside of the component.  But in my next version, I would like to make a component that can feed in the locationId to the observable when it loads and then each component manage their own state.

This looks like:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs"
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useObservable = (observable: Observable<any>, setter: Dispatch<SetStateAction<any>>) => {
 useEffect(()=>{
let subscription = observable.subscribe(result => {
    setter(result);
});
return ()=> subscription.unsubscribe()
 },[observable, setter])
}


const LocationItem: React.FC<LocationProps> = ({ location }) => {
   const [readings, setReadings] = useState<Array<Reading>>([]);
   const dataObservable = collectionData(
      db
      .collection('mimirReading')
      .where('locationId', '==', location.id)
      .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
      .limit(48)
  );

  useObservable(dataObservable, setReadings);
   return(
    <ol>
     {readings.map(r=><li>{r.timestamp}</li>)}
    </ol>
   )
}
```

The problem is, this results in the useObservable being called over and over and over again never giving back any data.  I end up with an empty readings state and my console going crazy.

I figured, I had to create the dataObservable when the component first mounts, so in useEffect, but then I would get errors related to calling useEffect inside itself. And lastly I tried pulling the subscription out and into the useEffect when first creating the component, but then the observable never collected any information.

Like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const dataObservable = collectionData(
      db
        .collection('mimirReading')
        .where('locationId', '==', location.id)
        .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
        .limit(48)
    ).subscribe((reads) => {
      console.log(reads);
      setReadings(reads as Array<Reading>);
    });
    console.log(dataObservable);
    return () => dataObservable.unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

I'm at a bit of a loss now and don't know what to do.  If anyone has any ideas or solutions it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the `useObservable` hook isolated, and create a observable value (memoized to the location id) to pass to it:

```js
const useObservable = (observable, setter) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let subscription = observable.subscribe(result => {
      setter(result);
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
    },
    [observable, setter]
  );
};

const LocationItem = ({ location }) => {
  const [readings, setReadings] = useState([]);

  const dataObservable = useMemo(() => {
    return collectionData(
      db
        .collection('mimirReading')
        .where('locationId', '==', location.id)
        .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
        .limit(48)
    );
  }, [location.id]);

  useObservable(dataObservable, setReadings);

  return (
    <ol>
      {readings.map((r) => (
        <li>{r.timestamp}</li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
};
```

Optionally, I'd further suggest changing the ownership of the state to `useObservable`:

```js
const useObservable = (observable) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    let subscription = observable.subscribe((result) => {
      setValue(result);
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [observable]);
  return value;
};
```

This way you don't need the outer state setter, it's always handled within the hook. You could also use `setState` within `useObservable` to capture the observable's error and complete events.

Comment: Good answer @backtick. However, please be aware that using `useMemo` like that is dangerous. Because [`useMemo` only serves as a hint, and doesn’t guarantee the computation won’t re-run](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-create-expensive-objects-lazily)